# Store MySQL table as PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table in a MySQL database containing a relatively low number of records(50-75), and I often need to use all of the records at once in my PHP code in the form of a multi-dimensional array. Now, as I rarely modify the records in the table, but need to use them very often in my PHP code, I would like to eliminate the need to read the records from the database every time I need them by making the page I use to modify the records generate valid PHP code containing the records. I would then simply include the generated code instead of connecting to and reading from the database anytime I need to.

To sum it up: I want to know how to, in PHP, take the entire contents of a MySQL table and write them in the form of a PHP array, such as this one:

```
$rows=array(
    array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'apples', 'amount'=>'250kg'),
    array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'oranges', 'amount'=>'89kg'),
    array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'bananas', 'amount'=>'4'),
...
    array('id'=>66, 'name'=>'potatoes', 'amount'=>'6t'));
```

Aside from the answer on how to do it, I would also like to know is it smart to do it? Would this open up any security holes, will it make my code run faster, and is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Sure, people do that. It's called "caching". Look it up, there's quite a few caching libraries out there undoubtedly.'

Comment: ^^ that answers "is there any other way to do this?" And caching is the better way, much better than hardcoding data in a bunch of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks for the comments. I have started using caching libraries as suggested. However, I have found the answer to my original question. It is the built-in PHP function `var_export()`, which outputs/returns a string representation of a value in a form which is also valid PHP code.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Answer (score 0):

You can save this data by means of a suitably protected json file and then use:

```
json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php